# Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found

Tags: python, linux, azure, docker

I am fairly new to Python and Azure web apps.  Any help is appreciated.

My setup:

- Program: Visual Studio code
- Language: Python-Flask
- Cloud provider: Microsoft Azure
- Database: Azure SQL DB
- Deployment option: Docker image > Azure container registry > Deploy the image to the Web app
- Web App OS: Linux (I think Alpine?)

In my code, I am using `pyodbc` to connect to the Azure SQL DB.  The code runs successfully locally in the terminal.  However, when it runs on the web, it encounters the following error:

`Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

I followed several troubleshooting posts, however, I have not been successful.

I tried using the $sudo ln to create a symbolic link that resulted in permission denied.  I think this is a known limitation of the Azure web app.

I tried to look for the driver in etc/odbcinst.ini to see if the driver name exists, however, I am pretty new to Azure / VS Code so I do not even know how to open the file that is in the, etc/ folder.  I do see it in the BASH command prompt when I navigate to the etc/ folder but not sure how to open the file.

I ran the following command in the `BASH` to install `PYODBC`, but that didn't resolve the issue.

```py
python -m pip install pyodbc
```

The result from `odbcinst -j`

```
    unixODBC 2.3.4
    DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
    SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
    FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
    USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/a49d42b0d7b8ce200a4f7e74/.odbc.ini
    SQLULEN Size.......: 8
    SQLLEN Size........: 8
    SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

My dockerFile:

```
# Pull a pre-built alpine docker image with nginx and python3 installed
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7

ENV LISTEN_PORT=8000
EXPOSE 8000

COPY /app /app

# Uncomment to install additional requirements from a requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

RUN apk add g++
RUN apk add unixodbc-dev
RUN pip install pyodbc
```

My requirements.txt.  I commented out `pyodbc`; I think that's okay since I am installing it in the docker file.

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
#pyodbc==4.0.28
```

Additional questions:

1. Should I be using PYODBC? or is there something better / more compatible I should be using?
2. Should I use MYSQL instead of Azure SQL DB?
3. Is there a way for me to open the `odbcinst.ini` file that is on the web app?

Answer (score 6):

First, if you want to know what os release is in your docker, you can command `cat /etc/os-release` to get it, such as run it in my ubuntu as the figure below.

[image]

At here, I'm sure your web app os is Alpine Linux, due to the first line of your docker file `FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7`. Your base image is based on Alpine 3.7.

Second, according to your error info `Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")` and the content of your docker file and `requirements.txt`, I think the issue was caused by missing MS SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux which not be installed in your docker image, but `pyodbc` required it to connect Azure SQL Database.

However, for `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`, the offical document [`Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server) shows there is not a released v17 package for Alpine. So the workaround is to change your DockerHub base image from `tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6-alpine3.7` to `tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6` to use debian as OS, then you can easily install MS ODBC driver 17 for SQL Server in it.

For your additional questions, as below.

1. Except for using `pyodbc`, `pymssql` is the other one of Python SQL Driver, please see the offical document [`Python SQL Driver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), but [`The Pymssql Project is Being Discontinued`](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql). And [`SQLAlchemy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html) as ORM framework can be used to connect Azure SQL Database, which also requires `pyodbc` or `pymssql`.
2. Use MySQL or Azure SQL Database, it's up to you. I think the only difference is that MySQL may be installed easiler than Azure SQL DB in Alpine.
3. The way to open `odbcinst.ini` file on webapp is to use vim over SSH to connect to your docker OS. Considering for the custom docker image you used, please see the section [`Enable SSH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh) of the offical document `Configure a custom Linux container for Azure App Service` and replace the command `apk` with `apt` for Debian Linux.

Answer (score 5):

The following instructions in the official website helped me solve my problem: [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

#Debian 8 (only supported up to driver version 17.6)
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Debian 9
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Debian 10
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
# optional: kerberos library for debian-slim distributions
sudo apt-get install -y libgssapi-krb5-2
```

Comment: [No support for Debian 11 yet](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6804#issuecomment-921227182).

Answer (score -1):

The official website instructions did not work for me as the packages were reported as missing:

```
$ sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql18
```

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc
```

Navigate with a browser too:

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod/pool/main/m/
```

Download the deb files in:

- `msodbcsql18`
- `mssql-tools18`
  Or
- `msodbcsql`
- `msodbcsql17`

Pick the version you want to install. I picked 18.

Install the two deb files:

```
sudo dpkg -i mssql-tools18_18.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i msodbcsql18_18.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb
```

If you had not run the script on the official website then you need to run the following (for 18 rather than 17):

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```